# ColdFusion 8 connectors not working with IIS-8

Tags: coldfusion

Coldfusion 8 installation on Windows 8.1 is causing issue. Since IIS-8.5 is the version of IIS, we are unable to create bindings using `wsconfig`. It looks like support is only till IIS 7.

Are there any updates/hotfixes for tackling this?

Comment: Is there an error?

Answer (score 4):

No there are no, and will be no further, updates for ColdFusion 8. End of life for ColdFusion 8 was back in July 31, 2012. Even if you had purchased extended support that ended on July 31, 2014. You should upgrade not only because of this connector issue but because there are several vulnerabilities with that older version that will never be patched.

[Adobe products and Enterprise Technical Support periods covered under the new Lifecycle Policy](https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/eol/eol_matrix.html#63)

[image]

Comment: Well, its not up to me to decide to upgrade, you must know how clients can be sometimes. Well I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, you can try to configure everything manually (without running wsconfig).  Steps are here - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/iis-configuration.html